# quadraticBezierTo Mirroring in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, quadratic-curve

I'm very new to flutter and I have been trying to create a modern drawer, and I have found one, the problem is the one I have found uses`quadraticBezierTo` and `enddrawer`which opens the drawer on the right to left but want to use`drawer` which opens the drawer form left to right. here is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50;
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    drawerScrimColor: Colors.grey.shade900.withOpacity(0.5),
     drawer: ClipPath(
        clipper: _DrawerClipper(),
        child: Drawer(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 48, bottom: 32),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue.shade200,
          child: DrawerHeader(
            child:Wrap(
           children:<Widget>[
             Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                maxRadius: 40,
                child: Image.asset("assets/profile.png"),
              ),
            ),
            Container(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0), alignment: Alignment.center,
             child:Text("Name",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white),
             ),
            ),
            Container( alignment: Alignment.center,
             child:Text("E-mail Address",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white),
             ),
             ),
           ],
           
            ),
          ),
          ),
        
        ListTile(
            title: Center(
                child: Text(
              "Item1",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),),],
    )),),),
```

and I use the following class for the `clipper`:

```
class _DrawerClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {  
@override
Path getClip(Size size) {
Path path = Path();

path.moveTo(50, 0);
path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height / 2, 50, size.height);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
return path;
}
@override
bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

and here is a photo of how it looks:

[image]

If I use `endDrawe`it looks normal but in my case I want to use `drawer`. I assume it has something to do with the `quadraticBezierTo` parameters but i'm not sure. how can I fix this?
Thanks for the help